# Efficient structure for pruning on job scheduling

Tags: np-complete, scheduling

This is an issue I encountered on several applications with different variants. But here is the common base for which I suspect to miss a more efficient approach.

There are $K$ different tasks to schedule on something (a product, some data, whatever...). Any order of actions is acceptable, but the cost (in time for exemple) of a task may be estimated with a complex function depending on the task and the combination of tasks already realized. The goal is to minimize the cost to achieve all tasks completion.

I use a bit array to keep track of the realized tasks (1=completed, 0=to do) and then explore the different paths with Dijkstra algorithm if $K$ is reasonable enough to look for optimal solution else with some heuristic variant. A state is a total cost and a task bit array.

Each time a new state is explored, one has to decide to eventually prune it. My idea is that if any other cheaper explored state (previously explored state using Dijkstra algorithm) has a greater task completion, it may be pruned. By greater, I mean that any task completed in the former is done in the latter. Using bitwise operations on two task bit arrays $A$ and $B$, it means:
$A \ge B \implies A \& B = B$
Note that this is not an ordering, there is no way to compare for exemple $0011$ and $0110$.

But of course, it is not efficient to test every previously explored state at every new one. The best solution I found until now, is to keep a list $L$ of previous states to compare to. When a new state $A$ is explored, I compare it to every state $S$ of $L$ :

- if $S \ge A$, $A$ is pruned (stop looping)
- else if $S \le A$, A replaces $S$ in $L$ and is accepted (stop looping)

if I reach the end of the loop without filling one of these two conditions, I append $A$ to $L$ and accept it.

But I feel that there is a more efficient structure for explored states. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't assume anything more about the "complex function" that returns the cost of a task, then in the worst case you will be forced to explore $\binom{n}{n/2}$ subsets of tasks.

Consider the following game for sake of argument. I play the role of the adversary (I decide the complex function) and you play the scheduler.
I (hidden from you) select a special set S of $n/2$ tasks. As long as you ask what is the cost of a task, I will return 0 for the first $n/2 - 1$ tasks. Then when you get to the $n/2$ task, I will return 0 if and only if the set of tasks you selected so far is exactly S, and otherwise I return a large value $M$. Since there is no way for you to find out any information about S until you selected $n/2$ elements, all you can do is try all possible subsets of $n/2$ tasks.

Comment: You are right, I need more assumptions on this cost function ...